# Alternative solution to use strwidth with out plot.new in r

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create layouts in R. For my layout,width will be based on the maximum width of the string in the dataset. I am using strwidth function to calculate the width of the string and then get the string width of the maximum string to pass it as a width value for the layout.

Code here,

```
max(strwidth(ds1$x))
j <- layout(matrix(c(0,3,2,1), 2,2, byrow = TRUE),
        widths = c(max(widthsize)*1.035,1-widthsize),
        heights = c(1,5))
```

But the problem is that, as per the documentation for strwidth, it is not allowing to use user units without plot.new(), when i try to use that, an empty plot is created everytime, i dont want that plot to be displayed with my output. Is there a way to avoid that or an alternative solution to calculate the string width. I tried to use different units for width calculation using units = "inches", but then widthsize is measured in different units for layout, so i am getting an error - Error in plot.new() : outer margins too large (figure region too small) while trying to plot on that layout.

Comment: can you add some data, the plot code, and desired output to play with?

Comment: I have mentioned the code above and the data can be anything, for example like this, df1$x <- ("New Hampshire", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Missouri"). The output should be a layout with its width being the maximum string size or bit more than that, thats why multiplying it by 1.035